# ModelState.Remove does not prevent context.savechangs from throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

How can I prevent context.savechangs from throwing errors on required attributes

I have this code to draft a message

this is the controller side method

```
    public string DraftMessage(message draftMessage, string status, HttpPostedFileBase[] files = null)
    {
        ModelState.Remove("Title");
        ModelState.Remove("Body");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new MessageActions().DraftMessage(draftMessage, status);
        }
        return "validation error";
    }
```

and this is the model method

```
    public string DraftMessage(message draftMessage, string status)
    {
        if (status == "new")
        {
            draftMessage = new message();
            draftMessage.Status = "DR";
            draftMessage.DateOfCreation = DateTime.UtcNow;
            draftMessage.C_From = CurrentUser.Id;
            context.messages.Add(draftMessage);
            draftMessage.To = new int[2];
            foreach (int receiverId in draftMessage.To)
            {
                if (context.users.Any(user => user.user_id == receiverId && (user.DepartmentOfTheUser.Company == CurrentUser.Company || user.DepartmentOfTheUser.CompanyOfTheDepartment.CompanyCustomers.Any(cus => cus.customer_of == CurrentUser.Company) || user.DepartmentOfTheUser.CompanyOfTheDepartment.CompanySuppliers.Any(supp => supp.supplier_of == CurrentUser.Company))))
                {
                    context.MessageReceiversConnectors.Add(new MessageReceiversConnector() { MessageId = draftMessage.id, ReceiverId = receiverId, MessageStatus = "DR" });
                }
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

        return "draft";
    }
```

I use the same entity created by entityframework to exchange the data and I used put the used the required attribute for validation, look at the code below

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage="This field is required")]        
    public int[] To { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]        
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]        
    public string Body { get; set; }
```

ModelState.Remove works on the controller side but when I reach to the model it throws exception on context.savechanges.

Is there any way to resolve this problem.

Comment: You should use view models instead.

Comment: is there any other way, this will take a lot of time to change my code to adapt the new changes

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by setting this option          `context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled` to false.